# how to append value in html through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

what i need

- i need to append data in html attribute value.

js code

```
var industrys=[];

for (var b = 0; b < obj.industry.length; b++)
{

    var indus=obj.industry[b];
    var temp = new Object();
    temp["value"] =indus.industry_url;
    temp["data"] = indus.id;
    industrys.push(temp);

}
$('.autocomplete_ind').autocomplete({
    lookup: industrys,

    onSelect: function(suggestion) {
        make_url('', suggestion.value);
        var thehtml = '<strong>industry name:</strong> ' + suggestion.name + ' selected<br> <strong>'+ suggestion.id+'</strong>';
        $('#outputcontent').html(thehtml);
        $(this).attr("value", suggestion.value);
    }
```

html

```
<input type="text"  autocomplete="off"  onChange="make_url()"
     id="industry_name"  class="biginput autocomplete_ind" 
     value="all data">
```

problem

- on doing view source value="all data"
- where im doing wrong.
- i have tried $(this).attr("value", suggestion.value); but on change event fires it reflect value-"blala etc".
- but on refresh or redirection value does not appended

like this

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" onchange="make_url()" id="industry_name" class="biginput autocomplete_ind" placeholder="All Industry" value="All industry">
```

now $(this).attr("value", suggestion.value); execute

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" onchange="make_url()" id="industry_name" class="biginput autocomplete_ind" placeholder="All Industry" value="agriculture-forestry">
```

but on refresh or redirection of page on view source value does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

`data()` is used to set the value of `data-*` attribute.

Use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set value of element.

Change

```
$(this).data('value', suggestion.value);
```

To

```
$(this).val(suggestion.value);
```

**Edit**

To append data use `append()`

Change

```
$('#outputcontent').html(thehtml);
```

To

```
$('#outputcontent').append(thehtml);
```

Comment: it was editing mistake:$(this).data('value', suggestion.value);

Comment: $(this).attr("value", suggestion.value); working fine but view source val does not exist

Comment: @afeef Check `Edit` in answer

Comment: @afeef Create `jsfiddle` of your problem

Comment: i have tried with automplete but i think its imposisble to append things to html b/c it doesnot reflect in view source

Comment: @afeef `create demo` means add the working code in the fiddle in the respected sections. Not just empty fiddle

Comment: can you help in i need to set the value selected from autocomplete js to value="some valeu selected" is it possible

Comment: json string : Object {value: "architecture", data: 56} html:      <input type="hidden" value="" id="c">